# How do I use Config Vars in Heroku to get my API key to work?

Tags: reactjs, api, heroku, api-key

So I have `.env` added to my `.gitignore` and in my `.env` file I have

```
REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY=123456
```

This was a recent add on, I already have this app fully deployed and working on Heroku. Do I just go to settings => Config Vars and add `key=REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY` and `value=123456`? How would I go about implementing my API key into Heroku within the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `key=` or `value=`, just set `REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY` to `123456` directly, either via [`heroku config:set`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-config-set):

```
heroku config:set REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY=123456
```

or [the dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard).

The `.env` file you're using in development and Heroku's config vars are both just convenient [ways of setting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#accessing-config-var-values-from-code) [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable):

> Config vars are exposed to your app’s code as environment variables. For example, in Node.js you can access your app’s `DATABASE_URL` config var with `process.env.DATABASE_URL`.

As long as you are using the `REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY` environment variable when your React application builds, or at runtime from your back-end (if you have one), you should be in business.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the edit and the answer. I've only been coding for a few months now. I don't currently have my heroku app connected to my terminal. In other words, I push all my code to my github and enabled automatic deploys to my heroku app. Do you have a walkthrough on how to do that with an already established and running heroku app? possibly this?: `heroku git:remote -a thawing-inlet-61413` (thawing-inlet-61413 as an example name)

Comment: @bgardne7, that's just [the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli). Stack Overflow isn't here to replace official documentation, so I suggest you take a look at that link and try installing it. It's very convenient. But in any case, you can set these values in the web dashboard as I have linked in my answer. That might be a lower-barrier option for you.

Comment: And yes, you can use `heroku git:remote -a <app-name>` to connect your local copy to an existing app called `<app-name>`.

Comment: Booyah! That did it, already had the Heroku CLI installed just needed to connect my app via `heroku git:remote -a <app name>` and then I ran `heroku config:set REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY=123456` and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the troubleshooting help!